# loading file on class construct

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm working on a sql class, and trying to figure out how to retrieve data from an external php file, to be available in the entire class.
Im guesing i have to do something like this:

```
class sqlQuery {
  protected $database = array();

  function __construct(){
    require_once (config.php);
  }
}

class model extends sqlQuery {
  function __construct() {
   $this->connect($this->database['hostname'], $this->database['user'], $this->database['pass'], $this->database['database']);
  }
}
```

The file might contain other information in the future, so I want it available to more then just the extended class.

Comment: The Model is not just the database. And the Model does not *behaves-as* a SqlQuery. You are misusing inheritance here. Inject your Query class through the constructor instead of extending Model from it. And inject config data to the Query object instead of requiring it inside.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is: do `parent::__construct()` in the extending class ctor, when you also want to invoke the parent's class ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should call parent constructor in class `model`:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // your other logic there
}
```

Then just change constructor of your parent class for filling `$this->database` array

Comment: Actually, it's `parent::__construct( )`, parent is constant, not a variable. Fixed it for you.